# Select value from dropdown menu in JXA

Tags: javascript, macos, applescript, javascript-automation

I have the following JXA code that selects a value from a drop-down menu

```js
export const selectFromPopUpList = (uiElements, value) => {
  for (const key in uiElements) {
    if (uiElements[key].class() === 'popUpButton') {
      uiElements[key].focused = true;
      uiElements[key].click();
      delay(0.2);
      SystemEvents.keystroke(value);
      delay(0.3);
      SystemEvents.keyCode(36);
      delay(0.4);
      uiElements[key].focused = false;
    }
  }
};
```

However, it doesn't seem to be reliable, the focus is sometimes lost, and the menu is never filtered when Enter is pressed. Is there a more reliable approach to selecting the value?

I've seen this bit of code somewhere, and it would be perfect for my use case

```js
 uiElements[key].menus[0].menuItems.byName(value).click();
```

But menus[0] doesn't seem to be defined in my case, maybe I'm using an older version of JXA / osascript? How can I check this?

Comment: Please create a code sandbox for your issue.